# ReactNative multiline TextInput not detecting taps on empty lines

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I've been trying to get my TextInput to focus (open keyboard) when I tap anywhere within the (gray) multiline box, but it is only detecting taps on lines with text (or the placeholder).

Is there any way to force the TextInput to focus when I click anywhere on the gray area?

```
   <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1}}>

    <View style = {Style.dropdownField}>
      <Dropdown
        label={'Motivo'}
        data={this.props.remiseExcusesData}
        value={this.state.remiseExcuses.value}            
        onChangeText={(value,index, data)=> this.setState({remiseExcuses:data[index]})}
      />
    </View>
    <View style = {{ height:150, marginHorizontal:20, backgroundColor:'#f9f9f9', marginTop:20}}>
    <TextInput
      style={Style.minitextInput}
      placeholder={'Escribir motivo'}
      textAlign={'left'}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize={'none'}
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
      multiline
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({motive:text})  }
      value={this.state.motive}
      onFocus={() => console.log('Fire only on tap')}
    />
    </View>
   </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for handle the focus of gray box.

```
<TouchableOpacity style = {{ height:150, marginHorizontal:20, backgroundColor:'#f9f9f9', marginTop:20}} onPress={this.onPressGrayBox}>
    <TextInput
      ref="textInput"
      style={{ height: 150, textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
      placeholder={'Escribir motivo'}
      textAlign={'left'}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize={'none'}
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
      multiline
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({motive:text})  }
      value={this.state.motive}

    />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

declare the method to handle the action, this will help to set textinput focus automatically.

```
onPressGrayBox=()=>{
  this.refs.textInput.focus()
}
```

This steps helps me, please use

Answer (score 0):

You can handle something like

```
   <View style = {{ height:150, marginHorizontal:20, backgroundColor:'#f9f9f9', marginTop:20}}>
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 150, textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
      placeholder={'Escribir motivo'}
      textAlign={'left'}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize={'none'}
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
      multiline
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({motive:text})  }
      value={this.state.motive}
      onFocus={() => console.log('Fire only on tap')}
    />
    </View>
```

Comment: You can also handle it by giving the style. Please see the answer i have updated